# Mysql can we have foreign key reference to multiple columns with OR condition?

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys, polymorphic-associations

I'm gonna migrate multiple DBs to one DB, all those DBs have same tables, the problem is duplicate keys, so for this reason I thought the easiest solution is to have `ex_id` in my main tables and then have a foreign key in child tables that should reference either to `id` or `ex_id`.

Can we have something like that, or any better solution ?

Note: I do not want to lose any data, they are the real live DBs.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No. A foreign key constraint names exactly which table and column(s) it references, and it must reference the same table and column(s) on every row.

I say column(s) because some constraints are multi-column, not because the foreign key can reference your choice of column.